# MySQLのSQLにてグループ内で連番を付けたい

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL 5.6を利用しています。

分析関数を持たないRDBMSのSQLでは、どのようなSQLを書くのが一般的でしょうか？
一般的ではなくとも、解決できるSQLがありましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

やりたいこと：

下記のテーブルがあります。

```
ユーザID 作成日時
--------------------------
10012   2015-01-04
10010   2015-01-01
10011   2014-01-15
10010   2015-01-02
10011   2015-12-09
10010   2015-01-03
10012   2015-11-01
10011   2015-05-08
10012   2015-01-03
```

SQLで下記の結果を取得したいです。
※「ユーザID」「作成日時」で昇順に並べかえて、
　グループ内（同じユーザID内）で通番を付与

```
ユーザID 作成日時   グループ内通番
-------------------------------
10010   2015-01-01 1
10010   2015-01-02 2
10010   2015-01-03 3
10011   2014-01-15 1
10011   2015-05-08 2
10011   2015-12-09 3
10012   2015-01-03 1
10012   2015-01-04 2
10012   2015-11-01 3
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL だとユーザー変数で連番をつけたりします。

```
set @no:=0;
set @user_id:=null;

select
  if(@user_id <> user_id, @no:=1, @no:=@no+1) as no,
  @user_id:=user_id as user_id,
  created_at
from t order by user_id, created_at
```

MySQL 特有の機能を使わないのであれば、次のように相関サブクエリを使うとかでしょうか。

```
select
  t1.user_id, t1.created_at, (
    select count(*) from t t2
      where t1.user_id = t2.user_id
        and t1.created_at >= t2.created_at
  ) as no
from t t1
order by
  t1.user_id, t1.created_at
```

（同値があるときの結果がちょっと変わりますが）

そのテーブルの主キーが `id` だとして、次のようにただのサブクエリでもいいかもしれません。

```
select
  t1.user_id,
  t1.created_at,
  sum(t1.created_at >= t2.created_at) as no
from t t1 inner join t t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
group by t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.created_at
order by t1.user_id, no
```

Comment: ユーザ変数を使う方法についてですが、 [マニュアル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/user-variables.html)に「1つのステートメントで複数回のユーザ変数を使った場合の評価順序が保証されない」とあります。 いいかえればOrderBy句のソート順かつ、Select句の左から右にユーザ変数が評価されることが保証されてませんので、 結果は保証されないと思います。(たいていは、期待した結果になるようですが)

Comment: そうなんですね、ユーザー変数をこういう使い方しない方がいいみたいですね

Answer (score 0):

ngyukiさんが投稿されてる
ユーザ変数を使う方法ですが

MySQLのマニュアルと
OracleACEのAketiJyuuzouさんとyoku0825さんと
日本オラクルの木村明治さんによると
MySQLのユーザ変数は評価順序が未定義です。
http://qiita.com/AketiJyuuzou/items/cced9b70cc714b382d98

なので結果が保証されません。